# Twitter typeahead default suggestions: how to get the first suggestions in the prefetched array?

Tags: javascript, twitter-typeahead

I am using Twitter Typeahead and I would like to offer some values to the user when the input box gets focus, before anything was typed.

There's an example for that on the [examples page](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) under Default Suggestions:

```
var nflTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  identify: function(obj) { return obj.team; },
  prefetch: '../data/nfl.json'
});

function nflTeamsWithDefaults(q, sync) {
  if (q === '') {
    sync(nflTeams.get('Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Chicago Bears'));
  }

  else {
    nflTeams.search(q, sync);
  }
}

$('#default-suggestions .typeahead').typeahead({
  minLength: 0,
  highlight: true
},
{
  name: 'nfl-teams',
  display: 'team',
  source: nflTeamsWithDefaults
});
```

However in the example, they hard-code the values they want to suggest:

```
      sync(nflTeams.get('Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Chicago Bears'));
```

In my case, I use Bloodhound with pre-fetch, and I want to suggest the first few options returned by the pre-fetch.

Edit: 
What I would like to show is the first few items returned by the server. The server will be responsible for the order of showing them. So in the above example, if data/nfl.json contains:

```
[
{ "team": "San Francisco 49ers" },
{ "team": "Chicago Bears" },
{ "team": "Cincinnati Bengals" },
{ "team": "Buffalo Bills" },
{ "team": "Denver Broncos" },
{ "team": "Cleveland Browns" },
...
```

I would just show whatever the first teams are. The number of teams shown could be a parameter.

How do I do that?

Comment: when you say `first few options`, how will you determine how many and which few ? can you please be more specific ?

Comment: The server is sending me an array. I could use the n first items in the array (says 6 or 10 first ones). It would be up to the server to decide on the sorting.

Answer (score 4):

For example, you want to display 2 first items in default

```
function nflTeamsWithDefaults(q, sync) {
    if (q === '') {
        sync(nflTeams.all().slice(0, 2)); // slice(start,end)
    }
    else {
        nflTeams.search(q, sync);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question asks for hep with BloodHound data source. So there is no `  source: nflTeamsWithDefaults` (in my understanding). It would be `source: nflTeams.ttAdapter()`. And there is no way to query with `nflTeamsWithDefaults`.